# My OnScrollListener is not being called, what is the code missing?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

My onScrollListener seems to never be being called. I follwed several other tutorials and embedded the onscrolllistener in my ArrayAdapter.However it doesn't log the events.

I followed this rough format which was working for him/her and the advice of his commenters but I couldn't get at it.

Whatis the code missing?

```
  package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.AbsListView;
  import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
  import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class ArticleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> implements OnScrollListener{

// declaring our ArrayList of items
private ArrayList<Article> objects;

/* here we must override the constructor for ArrayAdapter
* the only variable we care about now is ArrayList<Item> objects,
* because it is the list of objects we want to display.
*/
public ArticleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Article> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;


}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View v = convertView;

    // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
    // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_button, parent, false);
    }

    /*
     *   i refers to the current Item object.
     */
    Article i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        TextView heading = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        // check to see if each individual textview is null.
        // if not, assign some text!
        if (heading != null){
            heading.setText(i.getHeading());
        }

        ImageView featuredimage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.featuredimage);
        String imageUrl = i.getImageurl();
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this.getContext()));
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, featuredimage);

        Typeface museo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Museo_Slab_500.otf");
        heading.setTypeface(museo);
        heading.setTextSize(25);
    }
    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisibleItem,
                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    Log.v("entered onScroll", " " + firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount
            + totalItemCount);
    if (((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount - 1)) {
        Log.v("entered if", " " + firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount
                + totalItemCount);
        // if we're at the bottom of the listview, load more data
        addData(totalItemCount, 10);
    }
}

private void addData(int totalItemCount, int productId) {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "last item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have just implemented the interface and no listener is set on it.
You need to set the listener by saying listview.setOnScrollListener(this).
My recommendation would be to create a seperate class that implements the onscrolllisetner and that's class object passed to listview.setonscrolllisetener(new MyScrollListener());

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ya I get that in a basic sense however I was wondering where in the code exactly I implement that method ( listview.setOnscrollListe... ) as I don't explicity deal with the listview anywhere... Thanks again. I tried it where the listfragment is created but no such luck.

Comment: So I tried also to implement `ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setOnScrollListener(this);` in the adapter constructor above and it cannot find the method `findViewById` (and it's correctly spelled etc.)

Comment: Dude.. dont find the listview in your adapter.If you are using listfragment then there is a method called getListView(). This will return the listview object and you can set the onscrolllistener on that object as stated in answer above.

Comment: Thanks, however it's not working like it should.

`2527/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created`
            

Throws that on the line in the fragment. The only oddity it that the IDE is forcing me to use `implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener` rather than just onScrollListener.You know why?

Comment: This is my fragment in short `m_articles = manager.loadCategory(getActionBar().getTitle().toString(), 10);

m_artadapter = new ArticleAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.article_button, m_articles);
            this.setListAdapter(m_artadapter);

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
getListView().setOnScrollListener(new MyScrollListener());

return rootView;`

Comment: Now make your fragment implement the scrolllistener interface and instead of passing MyScrollListener instance pass this and you will be the notification in your fragment.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried that already and it still doesn't work. Thanks for your time btw much appreciated. I've seen several other people with a similar problem and no answer. I've copy and pasted myFragment below if you would still be willing to see what's up.

http://pastebin.com/EmpKLQwU

Comment: Are you getting the log in logcat that you have logged with Log.v?

Comment: nope, if you see in the logcat I posted above. The problem is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created`

Comment: Please move the view inflation code to the first line in the OnCreateView method and then get the listview object.

Comment: THat didn't work either... Is it possible I'm not using the  ListFragmetns default listview or something? Just spitballing here at this stage I'm going mad

Comment: Does your layout has listview with id @android:id/list?

Comment: Ya, check it out here... http://pastebin.com/0GqEytQf

Thanks for any help man, I'm going crazy...